Why does my .htaccess file not give proper access to a subdirectory that should inherit it
I am doing a school project for an introductory-level computer science course in high school.
I currently have a htaccess file in my directory with "Options +Indexes" inside it from a previous project, but for some reason the apache server refuses to provide me access to a specific directory that is two levels down from the one with the htaccess file.  I was told that these file settings are inherited and would like to ask what might be the issue and what could be some possible solutions.
i tried to view a file that I should have been able to view with my htaccess configuration, but i was unable to and was given an error message saying that the server failed to read the file, and refused access for safety.  There are no other .htaccess files in subdirectories between the one with the file and the targeted directory.

Did you allow .htaccess files in the server configuration?

There's not enough information here... we would likely need to see the file structure and server config. However, "...refused access for safety" does not sound like a normal server response. Please include a screenshot of this error response. You shouldn't need to add anything to .htaccess to grant access to subdirectories, unless you are specifically blocking access somewhere? Options +Indexes has nothing to do with granting access... this enables directory listings (part of mod_autoindex) when requesting directories. "I tried to view a file" - then Options +Indexes is irrelevant.

I dont know about this, i know that htaccess file are allowed as the file works properly for every subdirectory and all the contents that should be affected BUT that one directory.  I don't have access to the backend of apache cause i'm a student.  I have no idea how to actually use htaccess, i just know that i should be able to see the files in the directory when i can't (a friend is able to for his and he did the exact same thing)

Are you trying to access the directory itself, or a file inside the directory? What is the exact error message you are getting, please quote it verbatim.
